# why is myvar undefined after myvar = $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

So I am making a little game about a survivor in a desert. The survivor has to drink from wells scattered throughout the desert on his way back to Gold Rush Ghost Town. Some wells are good to drink from but others are poisoned. I am displaying a tooltip on those TD elements of a table that have the class "well". Inside the tooltip's initialization object, I need to get a reference to the current TD element, so I can pass it to a function that sets the tooltip's "content" property. Inside that function I must test if the current TD has the class "poisoned" too.

```
function initWellsTooltip() {
 $("#water-table tbody td.well").tooltip({

    content: function () {           
        var well$ = $( this );  // 
        // at this point stepping through the code in the debugger,
        // well$ is undefined and I don't understand why,
        // because $(this).hasClass("poisoned") succeeds.
        // VS2010 debugger shows as follows:
        //  ?$(this).hasClass("poisoned")
        //  true
        //  ?well$
        //  'well$' is undefined
        if (well$.hasClass("poisoned")) {
              return "poisoned!";
        } else {
            return "potable";
        }

    },
    items: "td.well",
    position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "left top" }

});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there are more `td.well`s than one, you have to iterate over them to set the correct `well$`

```
function initWellsTooltip() {
    $("#water-table tbody td.well").each(function() {
        var well$ = $(this);          

        well$.tooltip({
            content: function () {
                return well$.hasClass("poisoned") ? "poisoned!" : "potable";
            },
            items: "td.well",
            position: {
                my: "left+15 center",
                at: "left top"
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` at that instace don't refer to `$("#water-table tbody td.well")`. So you need to change it to an instacne of `$("#water-table tbody td.well")` as below,

```
function initWellsTooltip() {
 var that = $("#water-table tbody td.well");
 that.tooltip({

    content: function () {           
        var well$ = that;  // 
        // at this point stepping through the code in the debugger,
        // well$ is undefined and I don't understand why,
        // because $(this).hasClass("poisoned") succeeds.
        // VS2010 debugger shows as follows:
        //  ?$(this).hasClass("poisoned")
        //  true
        //  ?well$
        //  'well$' is undefined
        if (well$.hasClass("poisoned")) {
              return "poisoned!";
        } else {
            return "potable";
        }

    },
    items: "td.well",
    position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "left top" }

});
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I do not understand.  `$("#water-table tbody td.well")` returns more than one well, all of them, both the potable and the poisoned.

Comment: Maybe it is VS2010? I'm getting `'that' is undefined` error. I will try in Firebug.